# R ggpredict log transformed predictor

Tags: r, prediction, data-transform

My apologies if this is already discussed somewhere, I am mainly interested to know how to use `ggpredict()` when one of my covariate/predictor variable is `log transformed`. For example if this is my model.

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggeffects)
library(sjmisc)
library(lme4)
library(splines)
```

#### Create dataset

```
set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(
  outcome = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.35),
  var_binom = as.factor(rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.2)),
  var_cont = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 7),
  group = sample(letters[1:4], size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)

dat$var_cont <- sjmisc::std(dat$var_cont)
```

#### logistic regression model.

Please note here my predictor var_cont is log transformed.

```
m1 <- glmer(
  outcome ~ var_binom + log(var_cont) + (1 | group), 
  data = dat, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit")
)
```

#### GG predict on log transformed variable ?

```
 ggpredict(m1, "var_cont" ????)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show?  For example, `plot(ggpredict(m1, "var_cont"))` does something.  If that isn't what you want, you'll have to let us know what kind of output you are trying to get.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, sorry for not clearly stating my question. My goal is to estimate the predicted values of y, (y_hat), one of my predictors is log transformed, `log(var_cont)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on exactly what you want.  Here are a few possibilities:

```r
library(ggeffects)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(
  outcome = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.35),
  var_binom = as.factor(rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.2)),
  var_cont = abs(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 7)),
  group = sample(letters[1:4], size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)

m1 <- glmer(
  outcome ~ var_binom + log(var_cont) + (1 | group), 
  data = dat, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Just doing `ggpredict(m1, "var_cont")` will give you predicted values of `y` for the original values of `x` (not the logged values, `ggpredict()` does the transformation for you automatically).

```r
ggpredict(m1, "var_cont")
#> Data were 'prettified'. Consider using `terms="var_cont [all]"` to get
#>   smooth plots.
#> # Predicted probabilities of outcome
#> 
#> var_cont | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------
#>        0 |      0.00 |             
#>        5 |      0.36 | [0.24, 0.50]
#>       10 |      0.38 | [0.25, 0.52]
#>       15 |      0.39 | [0.25, 0.55]
#>       20 |      0.40 | [0.25, 0.57]
#>       25 |      0.40 | [0.24, 0.59]
#>       30 |      0.41 | [0.23, 0.61]
#>       35 |      0.41 | [0.23, 0.62]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * var_binom = 0
#> *     group = 0 (population-level)
ggpredict(m1, "var_cont", type="re")
```

The code above does not incorporate the random effect at all, as it uses `type="fe"` by default.  You could include the random effect variance in the calculation of the confidence intervals, which would be prediction intervals if the random effect variance is used.  This doesn't change the predictions themselves, only the variance.

```r
#> Data were 'prettified'. Consider using `terms="var_cont [all]"` to get
#>   smooth plots.
#> # Predicted probabilities of outcome
#> 
#> var_cont | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------
#>        0 |      0.00 |             
#>        5 |      0.36 | [0.07, 0.81]
#>       10 |      0.38 | [0.07, 0.83]
#>       15 |      0.39 | [0.08, 0.83]
#>       20 |      0.40 | [0.08, 0.84]
#>       25 |      0.40 | [0.08, 0.85]
#>       30 |      0.41 | [0.08, 0.85]
#>       35 |      0.41 | [0.08, 0.86]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * var_binom = 0
#> *     group = 0 (population-level)
#> 
#> Intervals are prediction intervals.
```

Finally, if you wanted to include the estimate of the random intercept in the calculation of the prediction, you can add your grouping variable `"group"` into the terms being considered and use `type="re"`.  This gives prediction rather than confidence intervals, but gives a different set of predictions for each group using the group-level intercepts.

```r
ggpredict(m1, c("var_cont","group"), type="re")
#> Data were 'prettified'. Consider using `terms="var_cont [all]"` to get
#>   smooth plots.
#> # Predicted probabilities of outcome
#> 
#> # group = a
#> 
#> var_cont | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------
#>        0 |      0.00 |             
#>        5 |      0.32 | [0.06, 0.78]
#>       15 |      0.35 | [0.06, 0.81]
#>       20 |      0.35 | [0.06, 0.82]
#>       35 |      0.37 | [0.06, 0.83]
#> 
#> # group = b
#> 
#> var_cont | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------
#>        0 |      0.00 |             
#>        5 |      0.31 | [0.06, 0.78]
#>       15 |      0.34 | [0.06, 0.80]
#>       20 |      0.35 | [0.06, 0.81]
#>       35 |      0.36 | [0.06, 0.83]
#> 
#> # group = c
#> 
#> var_cont | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------
#>        0 |      0.00 |             
#>        5 |      0.40 | [0.08, 0.84]
#>       15 |      0.43 | [0.09, 0.85]
#>       20 |      0.44 | [0.09, 0.86]
#>       35 |      0.45 | [0.09, 0.87]
#> 
#> # group = d
#> 
#> var_cont | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------
#>        0 |      0.00 |             
#>        5 |      0.42 | [0.09, 0.85]
#>       15 |      0.45 | [0.10, 0.87]
#>       20 |      0.46 | [0.10, 0.87]
#>       35 |      0.48 | [0.10, 0.89]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * var_binom = 0
#> 
#> Intervals are prediction intervals.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In all these cases, the predictions are made for the original values of `x`, rather than the logged values.  If you wanted the plot on the log scale, you could add `scale_x_log10()` to the plot

One other piece of advice, I noticed that you had `dat$var_cont <- sjmisc::std(dat$var_cont)` in your code (which I removed).  This will cause all sorts of problems if you go on to log `var_cont` as roughly half of the observations will be non-positive and thus turned to `NA` by the log transformation.  In general, your observations should be strictly positive for the log transformation.  If your variable includes zero, an inverse hyperbolic sine transformation `asinh()` in R, would work.  If your variables include negative values, too, and require transformation then try the `powerTransform()` function from the `car` package with family `family="bcnPower"`.

Comment: here you said, "(not the logged values, ggpredict() does the transformation for you automatically).",  I am confused.

Comment: You have in the model `log(var_cont)`, so what happens is that `ggpredict()` generates values across the range of `var_cont` plugs those values into the `log()` function and generates predictions.  So what `ggpredict()` gives you is the predicted value of `y` for several values of `var_cont` (on its original scale, not on the log scale).

Comment: ah thanks, I just created a variable, `x2 = og(var_cont)` and use that variable `x2` in the model.